# Split project date range into rows of work weeks for all projects in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a projects table with a total_hours column and a startdate, enddate column.
If a project has a date range of 5 weeks, I need a query that returns 5 rows with the incremented work week number in a calculated field for all projects.

Here is my table data with a query showing the range in work week format.

```
drop table #temp


CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (ProjectID int, Total_Hours int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #Temp
    (ProjectID, Total_Hours, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES
    (645, 555, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (700, 234, '2015-01-14 00:00:00', '2016-02-01 00:00:00')



    Select datepart(week,startdate),datepart(week,Enddate) from #Temp
```

I need a query that will return the following values

```
ProjectID   WW
645         1
645         2
645         3
645         4
645         5
645         6
700         3
700         4
700         5
700         6
```

I feel I should use recursion but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with recursion but a numbers table is generally more efficient:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select t.projectid, dateadd(week, n.n, t.startdate) as ww
from #Temp t join
     n
     on dateadd(week, n.n, t.startdate) <= t.enddate;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a recursive query, use

```
with t as (
 select projectid,datepart(week,startdate) sw,datepart(week,enddate) ew from #Temp
 union all
 select projectid,sw+1,ew from t where sw < ew
     )
select projectid, sw 
from t 
order by 1,2
```

[Sample Demo](http://rextester.com/MSDO98538)